# Why are arrays equal to their corresponding strings?

Tags: javascript, arrays, reference, equality

Why is an array evaluated to true when it is compared to its corresponding string?

```js
var a = [1,2,3];
var b = '1,2,3';

console.log(a==b);// true
```

Variable `a` stores the memory address of the array it is assigned. Then how is a memory address equal to corresponding string of that array.

Comment: Though I don't know the exact mechanics of `==`, it's important to realize that it does not perform a strict comparison. When the operands are of different types, it first tries to convert them to the same type before comparing them. If you want to do a strict comparison, you would want to use `===`, which in your case would return `false`.

Comment: a is being coerced to a string for comparison

Answer (score 1):

Well in case of "==", array is converted to `toString` and then compared due to loose comparison, so it equates to true.  So what happens is this:

```
  var a = [1,2,3];
  var b = '1,2,3';

  a == b //is same as
  a.toString() === b //true
```

If you want to evaluate to true in a strict mode, you may also do something like this:

```js
var a = [1,2,3];
var b = '1,2,3';

a = a.join(',')

console.log(b === a);
```

Whenever you're loose comparing (with '=='), javascript interpreter tries it best to to convert both values to a common type and match them. To quote [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Equality_comparisons_and_sameness#:~:text=Loose%20equality%20using%20%3D%3D,exactly%20as%20%3D%3D%3D%20performs%20it.)

> Loose equality compares two values for equality, after converting both
>   values to a common type. After conversions (one or both sides may
>   undergo conversions), the final equality comparison is performed
>   exactly as === performs it.

Now your confusion is,

*what variable a stores inside it , is just memory address of the array . So in first code snippet you say that a==b is same as a.toString==b but whats inside a is a memory address ,so when a memory address is converted to a string how is it equal to corresponding strings of an array.*

Well, note here when you comparing two variables, you're not comparing the memory address of them but the values stored at them :) So it's not the memory address that is getting converted to `toString` but the value stored at it.

Also, there's one more flaw in this thinking.

consider,

```
        var a = 4, // a holds address of variable a
        b =4; //b holds the address of variable b
```

Now, these two variables are definitely holding different memory addresses so they wouldn't have been equated to `true` which is not true. I hope you got the point.

Comment: i have read that, what variable a stores inside it , is just memory address of the array . So in first code  snippet you say that a==b is same as a.toString==b but whats inside a is a memory address ,so when a memory address is converted to a string how is it equal to corresponding strings of an array. Please explain i am perplexed by this problem from several days.

Comment: Well, when you're comparing two variables, you're comparing the values stored at the addressed and not the actual addresses. You don't compare  `address of a == address of b` when you're writing `a==b`.

Comment: See the updated answer and let me know if it clears the confusion

Answer (score 1):

It is due to the specs and semantics of the language.  The array, which is an Object, will be coerced to a string before comparison to a string.

You can follow the conversion path:
[7.2.15 Abstract Equality Comparison](https://tc39.es/ecma262/#sec-abstract-equality-comparison)

> 11. If Type(x) is Object and Type(y) is either String, Number, BigInt, or Symbol, return the result of the comparison ? ToPrimitive(x) == y.

It basically passes through all the steps until it gets to *11.*.
`ToPrimitive(Array)` eventually ends up referencing and calling the property `.toString`
https://tc39.es/ecma262/#sec-array.prototype.tostring
https://tc39.es/ecma262/#sec-object.prototype.tostring

Answer (score 0):

== compares two variables irrespective of data type while === compares two variables in a strict check, which means it checks for data type also then it returns true or false.

The ‘==’ operator tests for abstract equality i.e. it does the necessary type conversions before doing the equality comparison.

But the ‘===’ operator tests for strict equality i.e it will not do the type conversion hence if the two values are not of the same type, when compared, it will return false.